# Python tkinter: NameError: name 'tk' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

```
from tkinter import*


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=500)
canvas.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Why does this error come up?
I have installed tkinter, so I dont know why it's saying this.

Comment: `from tkinter import* as tk`?  You never declare `tk`.

Comment: How did you install `tkinter`?

Comment: ay thx that solved it

Answer (score 1):

tkinter is the package name. If you do a `from tkinter import *`  you do not need any prefixes.

The `tk.` prefix is used when you import tkinter with

`import tkinter as tk`

Which is preferred over doing a star import, as it preserves the namespaces: there are hundreds of names in the tkinter package that upon doing `from tkinter import *` will be brought to the global namespace, making it hard to tell what is a variable you created, what is a Python built-in name, and what is part of the tkinter package. By doing `import tkinter as tk`, you can use and read everything tkinter prefixing it with `tk.` which is  both easy to read and to type.

Answer (score -2):

you have 2 options

1. `

   import tkinter as tk
   from tkinter import*

   root = tk.Tk()

   canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=500)
   canvas.pack()

   root.mainloop()

   `

or

```
from tkinter import*


root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=500)
canvas.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

you have to define tk first or you have to use tkinter instead of tk

Comment: The second option is not valid it would be: root=Tk()

Answer (score -3):

I think may be have a file with name tkinter.py in your current source code folder

Comment: No, this is not the root of the problem.